# Link to Google Play Store from within WebView using only JavaScript

Tags: android, web-applications, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

Long story short: I created a mobile webapp a while ago and it seems fairly popular, especially on Android. Today I discovered someone created an Android App and listed it in Google's Play Store that just wraps my website.

My plan is now to create an Android Application myself, then show a message to users using this app that there is "a new version" of the app they can "upgrade" to in order to keep using my webapp.

I already know how to identify the set of users who are using this app from within JavaScript land, however I want to make transition as smooth as possible (ideally having the users click a button and be in the Play Store's page where there is a [Install] button). I've been reading lots of answers on this topic here but they all assume that one is in control of the android code, which I'm not:

Is there a way to break out of an WebView to a specific page in Google's Play Store ?

If all else fails, the message can say "please search for 'name of the new app' in play store", however that seems not ideal from a UX point of view.

Comment: why not give the play store link of your app ?

Comment: Because I suppose the user experience of writing that down on a piece of paper then typing it in the browser would not be optimal.

Comment: and why would it not show up as a link since its a WebView ?

Comment: It would, but it would be opened within the WebView. Then the market:// link on the play store page wouldn't open because that's prohibited (at least that's what I make of the other answers).

Comment: Might as well try since, it depends on how the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is implemented.